# how to substring in javascript but excluding symbols

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I need to use (substring method) in my javascript web network project, but excluding `:` colon symbol, because it is hexadecimal ip address, and I don't want to accept `:` colons as a string or lets say number in the substring, I want to ignore it. How to do that?

This is the example IPV6 in the input field:

```
2001:2eb8:0dc1:54ed:0000:0000:0000:0f31
```

after substring from 1 to 12:

```
001:2eb8:0d
```

as you can see it accepted colons also, but in fact, I need this result:

```
2001:2eb8:0dc1
```

so by excluding these two symbols, it would have gave me that result above, but I don't know how.

and here is the code, IpAddressInput, is only a normal input field which I write the ip address in it.

Here is the code:

```
    var IpValue = $('#IpAddressInput').val();
    alert(IpValue.substr(1, (12) -1));
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I added the code, any else needed? let me know

Comment: *I need to use substring method* - do you?  Is the requirement that you use `substring()`, and nothing else?  Your code is using `.substr()` not `.substring()` - note that .substr [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: "IpAddressInput" - so will the input always be in the format `\d{4}:\d{4}:\d{4}:...` - seems you could get your result by using `.substr(1,13)`  (14-1)

Comment: If your format is fairly robust, a basic method might be `var s = "2001:2eb8:0dc1:54ed:0000:0000:0000:0f31"; var add = s.substring(0, 11).split(":").length; console.log(s.substring(0, 11+add))` but will mess up if you have colons around the end - so probably better just to loop each character until you get to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1:** I think there is no direct function to results like you want but this answer will help you. I counted the number of colons from index 0 to 12 and then slice the source string from 0 to 12 plus the number. Here is the code:

```js
let val = "2001:2eb8:0dc1:54ed:0000:0000:0000:0f31";
let numOfColons = val.slice(0, 12).match(/:/g).length;
let result = val.slice(0, 12 + numOfColons);
console.log(result)
```

**Answer 2:** If you are sure that there is a colon after exactly every 4 characters, a better solution will be this. The idea is to remove all colons from the string, slice from index 0 to 12, and add a colon after every 4 characters. Finally, it removes the last colon. Here is the code:

```js
let value = "2001:2eb8:0dc1:54ed:0000:0000:0000:0f31";
let valueExcludeColon = value.replace(/:/g, ''); // '20012eb80dc154ed0000000000000f31'
let result = valueExcludeColon.slice(0,12).replace(/(.{4})/g, "$1:"); // '2001:2eb8:0dc1:'
let finalResult = result.slice(0, -1); // 2001:2eb8:0dc1
console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: If you are sure there is a colon in those places, then just `val.slice(0,14)`